# SQL Server how to find specific data across entire database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this script which finds all tables that contain data in column `RGNCODE`. I'm trying to amend this to find tables that contain a specific value for rgncode across all tables. So `RGNCODE = 'UK'`. Unsure where to add this in?

```
SELECT
   sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
   tables.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
WHERE
   sys.columns.name = 'rgncode' and 
   tables.name in (
      SELECT [TableName] = so.name
      FROM sysobjects so, sysindexes si
      WHERE so.xtype = 'U' AND si.id = so.id
      GROUP BY so.name
      HAVING max(si.rows) > 0 
   )
```

Comment: You'll have to use dynamic SQL for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic statement, using system catalog views, is an option here:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''

SELECT @stm = @stm +
    CASE WHEN @stm = N'' THEN '' ELSE N'UNION ALL ' END +
    N'SELECT ''' +
    QUOTENAME(sch.[name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(tab.[name]) + ''' AS TableName FROM ' +
    QUOTENAME(sch.[name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(tab.[name]) +
    N' WHERE RGNCODE = ''UK'' HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 '
FROM sys.columns col
JOIN sys.tables tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
WHERE col.[name] = 'RGNCODE'

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following cursor will help you:

```
CREATE TABLE ##DataTable
 (TblName VARCHAR(100),RowNum INT)
 GO

DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SQLText AS nVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableCount AS INT
DECLARE TableDect CURSOR
FOR 

SELECT
tables.name AS TableName
FROM
sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON
sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
WHERE
sys.columns.name = 'rgncode' and tables.name in (
SELECT
[TableName] = so.name
FROM
sysobjects so,
sysindexes si
WHERE
so.xtype = 'U'
AND
si.id = so.id
GROUP BY
so.name
HAVING max(si.rows) >0 )
OPEN TableDect
FETCH NEXT FROM TableDect INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
SET @SQLText =  N'SELECT @NumberOUT=COUNT(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '  WHERE rgncode=''UK'''
SET @TableCount = 0
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLText ,N'@NumberOUT nvarchar(25) OUTPUT' ,@NumberOUT=@TableCount OUTPUT
 INSERT INTO ##DataTable values(@TableName,@TableCount)
FETCH NEXT FROM TableDect INTO @TableName
END 
CLOSE TableDect;

DEALLOCATE TableDect


SELECT * FROM  ##DataTable
```